# How to draw a bitmap from AChartEngine GraphicalView

Tags: android, canvas, achartengine, ondraw

I have an app that receives in real time messages from a range sensor and I want to update a chart with the values received.
I decided to use a `GraphicalView` from the library `AChartEngine`.
I thought to update the `Graphicalview` every time that I receive a message then to convert it in a `BitMap` with the `toBitmap()` function and then to draw the bitmap on a canvas.

I'm trying to see if I can do this (so I'm not using messages yet but only trying to draw a bitmap from  a graphical view) but when I run my code I get a `Nullpointer exception`. This is my code:

```
public class DrawChartView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
Rect rect = new Rect(130, 130, 80, 80);
Context context;
XYSeries currentDataset = new XYSeries("range data series");
XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
XYSeriesRenderer currentRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
LineChart lc;
GraphicalView gv;
Bitmap bm;

public DrawChartView(Context context_) {
    super(context_);
    context = context_;
    //imposto i parametri del renderer
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(10);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(currentRenderer);
    //imposto il dataset
    currentDataset.add(1,1);
    currentDataset.add(2,2);
    currentDataset.add(3,3);
    mDataset.addSeries(currentDataset);
    //inizializzo il line chart
    lc = new LineChart(mDataset, mRenderer);
    //inizializzo la grahical view
    gv = new GraphicalView(context, lc);
    bm=gv.toBitmap();
}

public DrawChartView(Context context_, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context_, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DrawChartView(Context context_, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context_, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    //canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
   // canvas.drawBitmap(bm,new Rect(0,0,100,100),rect,null);

}

public void setRect(int h, int b)
{
    rect.set(130,130,30+b,30+h);

}

public void setChart(XYSeries xys)
{
    mDataset.addSeries(xys);
    lc = new LineChart(mDataset, mRenderer);
    gv= new GraphicalView(context, lc);
    bm = gv.toBitmap();

}
```

The activity:

```
public class FragActivity extends Activity {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();   
    XYSeries currentSeries = new XYSeries("range data series1");
    DrawChartView dcv/* = new DrawChartView(this)*/;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag);


        dcv = (DrawChartView)findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView01);
        dcv.onDraw(canvas);
        currentSeries.add(11, 11);
        dcv.setChart(currentSeries);
        dcv.onDraw(canvas);
    }


    }
```

And the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<com.cami.robot_chooser.DrawChartView 
    android:id="@+id/SurfaceView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/show_message1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can you help to figure what's wrong and how to fix the problem?

LogCat said:

```
    10-22 12:52:06.115: I/Choreographer(3061): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 12:52:06.155: D/gralloc_goldfish(3061): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-22 12:52:08.406: I/Choreographer(3061): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 12:52:08.581: D/AndroidRuntime(3061): Shutting down VM
10-22 12:52:08.581: W/dalvikvm(3061): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.cami.robot_chooser/com.cami.robot_chooser.FragActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3228)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at com.cami.robot_chooser.DrawChartView.<init>(DrawChartView.java:36)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at com.cami.robot_chooser.FragActivity.<init>(FragActivity.java:41)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
10-22 12:52:08.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3061):     ... 11 more
10-22 12:52:13.545: I/Process(3061): Sending signal. PID: 3061 SIG: 9
```

Comment: you need to post the stacktrace

Comment: I can see the log cat but I don't now how to see the stack trace console, how can i find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please make sure you have the added the permission to save files on the external storage in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you have this and it still doesn't work then please take a look at the discussions around this topic [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=115) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=98).

Comment: I added the permission but still get the same null pointer exception, the log cat said: "Unable to instantiate activity Componentinfo {com.cami.robot_chooser/com.cami.robot_chooser.FragActivity} java.lang.NullPointerexception

Comment: I don't know how to get the stack trace

Comment: Copy it from LogCat and paste it here.

Comment: Done and added to the question

Comment: The chart must be visible on screen when calling toBitmap()

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with aChartEngine charts returning null bitmaps. There are various proposed solutions around the place for this, but none of them worked for me (they all failed while trying to measure the size of the necessary bitmap). For my purposes, the bitmap needs to be a fixed size, and the following code works nicely:

```
private Bitmap bitmapFromChartView(View v, int width, int height) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
        height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, width, height);
v.draw(c);
return b;
}
```

You can then call it with something like:

```
Bitmap x = bitmapFromChartView(myGraphicalViewObject, 500, 500);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, as well.  Apparently, there is an issue with something in the implementation of renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(bool) method.

Set this value to FALSE and hopefully this will resolve your issue.... to some extent.  You still have to figure out what you are going to do about zooming --- but at least the app runs.  :)